# Include Timezone in Log

Tags: c#, timezone, serilog

How do I include the timezone in the log so that the entry appears as follows:

`2020-07-08 08:03:35.677 EST [INF] This is the entry text.`

Note that there is no UTC reference; it has been replaced with 'EST' or whatever is appropriate for the timezone.

Comment: What's your outputTemplate?

Comment: As far as I can google, you may be able to get an offset by using the "zzz" template, but I found nothing to get in the actual TimeZone.

Comment: Note that I would be interested in a solution for WriteTo.Console and WriteTo.Async. Thanks!

Comment: To Filidor: I guess that's the point of the question...what would be the appropriate outputTemplate.

Comment: That's why I asked for yours, so we can suggest changes to it. Did you try adding "zzz" to the timestamp's format template? I am afraid, that's as close as you can get, outside maybe "K".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fildor. As far as I can tell, zzz is for abbreviating Information, Error and Warning. It seems redundant to add another timestamp. And it seems awkward to have the timezone outside of the timestamp provided by serilog.

Comment: `.WriteTo.File(
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message ...` That's what I meant ... Like here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#controlling-event-formatting

Answer (score 2):

.NET doesn't provide a built-in way to emit time zone abbreviations.  If you really need them, you could import my [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) library and do something like the following:

```
static string GetTimeZoneAbbreviation(DateTimeOffset dto, TimeZoneInfo tzi)
{
    var abbreviations = TZNames.GetAbbreviationsForTimeZone(tzi.Id, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);
    return tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(dto) ? abbreviations.Daylight : abbreviations.Standard;
}
```

Pass `TimeZoneInfo.Local` if you inteded the local time zone to be used.

I'll leave wiring it up to Serilog up to you (or someone else).

That said - you might want to reconsider why you want this at all.  In most cases, the offset from UTC (using the `zzz` specifier) is preferred in log files.  One reason is that not every time zone has a unique abbreviation.

For example, if `"CST"` appears in your logs, how will you know whether that is US Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, or China Standard Time?  Without an offset, there won't be any way to tell.

Additionally, be aware that not every time zone has an abbreviation at all.  Many time zones, even with my library in place, will return an offset to use in place of an abbreviation.

In other words, the *concept* of a time zone abbreviation is not universally accepted.  It is mostly a [Western](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_world) idea.

Comment: Thanks Matt. My application is oriented towards a US-only IT group. The timezone is a convience, granted, but useful for auditing, etc.I can generate the abbreviation, i just can't inject it into Serilog in the desired fashion.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a custom class deriving from `ITextFormatter` or `ILogEventEnricher`.  There are several examples of both if you search.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I worked up was to utilize outputTemplate. Knowing the timezone abbreviation, I performed the following:

```
    private static string OutputTemplate()
    {
        string timeZone = DetermineTimeZone();
        string outputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} "
                        + timeZone
                        + " [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";

        return outputTemplate;
    }

    string logFile = GetLogFileName();
    string outputTemplate = OutputTemplate();

    using (var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(logFile, outputTemplate: outputTemplate))
        .CreateLogger())
    {
        log.Information(logMessage.Message);
    }
```

with the resulting output:

2020-07-09 13:24:55.817 EDT [INF] Log Message ...